# MAMP with php extension intl on osx

Tags: php, macos, mamp, intl

I need to setup a project base on CakePhp FW, so I need to enable intl extension.

I followed [this tutorial](http://aerendir.me/2015/07/17/how-to-install-php-intl-module-in-mamp/) , but I always get `make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1` even though I created symbolic link between MAMP and the directory containing XCode php development headers by using this command (after excute I got file exist result)

`ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.6`

I am not familiar with MAC OS, so please help

**System Info**

- OSX: High Sierra 10.13.4
- MAMP Pro 4
- PHP 7.1.6

If you need more info, please let me know

Comment: could you solve this problem?

Comment: not yet, so I decided to use Windows